# React: AppStore listener must be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

fellow devs!

I have been digging into Flux / React with thanks to the tutorials over at Egghead. Although I have heard that React is moving, I have met with some changes in the React library while following said tutorials.

Up until now I have been able to fix them all. Now, I have run into a brick wall concerning the Store. As the tutorial states, I am making a shopping cart, in which the user can add things to their cart. Not that complicated. The actual adding works, but the re-rendering is not triggered. The following code gives the added error (full code will be listed below as well):

```
addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
},
```

Which results in *Uncaught TypeError: listener must be a function*. The callback parameter is undefined (so that's where the problem lies). However, because I am more than new React's way of working, I'm having trouble in locating the problem. The following snippet is the Store from the tutorial:

```
var AppStore = assign(EventEmitter.prototype, {

    emitChange: function() {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },
    addChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },
    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.removeChangeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },
    getCart: function() {
        return _cartItems;
    },
    getCatalog: function() {
        return _catalog;
    },
    getCartTotals: function() {
        return _cartTotals();
    },
    dispatcherIndex: AppDispatcher.register(function (payload) {
        var action = payload.action;

        switch(action.actionType) {
            case AppConstants.ADD_ITEM:
                _addItem(payload.action.item);
                break;
            case AppConstants.REMOVE_ITEM:
                _removeItem(payload.action.index);
                break;
            case AppConstants.INCREASE_ITEM:
                _increaseItem(payload.action.index);
                break;
            case AppConstants.DECREASE_ITEM:
                _decreaseItem(payload.action.index);
                break;
        }

        AppStore.emitChange();

        return true;
    })
});
```

Take note that this is code from a tutorial at Egghead.io and I am in no-way the owner (and if they so wish I will remove said code).

If more code or explanation is required, I'll be happy to oblige!

Thanks people :)

EDIT 1: The component that is supposed to listen to change, but does not:

```
var Cart = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return cartItems();
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        debugger;
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        debugger;
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    },
    handleChange: function() {
        debugger;
        this.forceUpdate();
    },
    _onChange: function() {
        debugger;
        this.setState(cartItems());
    },
    render: function() {
        var total = 0;
        var items = this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
            var subtotal = item.cost * item.qty;
            total +=subtotal;
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><RemoveFromCart index={i} /></td>
                    <td>{item.title}</td>
                    <td>{item.qty}</td>
                    <td>
                        <Increase index={i} />
                        <Decrease index={i} />
                    </td>
                    <td>${subtotal}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        });

        return (
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="4" className="text-right">Total</td>
                        <td>${total}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a small, working example of the problem? Additionally, have you tried debugging the code to see *why* the callback is null? Where are you calling "addChangeListener" from? I'm presuming a component?

Comment: I would if I could, but we're talking about some 20'ish files and the added problem of copyright to the actual code (as I'm not entirely sure where the boundaries for copying/distributing of said code lies). 

Basically, the `_addItem(payload.action.item)` function is called which triggers the `Appstore.emitChange()` line. That in turn, triggers the `emitChange: function()` line, which triggers `addChangeListener: function(callback)` line. Naturally, callback is undefined.. But I don't know enough about React to right this one :/

Comment: Why /how does `emitChange` call `addChangeListener`? It shouldn't. Which function is called when the event is emitted? Seems like you didn't wire up your code correctly. This has nothing to do with React btw. We can't really help you if we don't know how `addChangeListener` is called.

Comment: You are right Felix Kling- I was mistaken. See my first  comment for christopher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you've worked out most of this pattern but you've got a little confused. There's one last step that you need to include, and that is actually subscribing your components to the events that the store is pushing out.

```
this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
```

This will simply push something out. If no-one is listening, then nothing will know to change, so in your components, you need to actually listen for this event.

For a component, that might look something like:

```
React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        // Called after react has rendered the HTML in the DOM.
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>{AppStore.someData}</div>
    },

    handleChange: function() {
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
});
```

***NOTE***: `this.emit` should not be calling `addChangeListener`. It should be triggering the callbacks that you have *subscribed* using the `addChangeListener` method.

**Potential Improvements**

- One thing to note is that, despite all your data being in the `AppStore`, not all of your components will care about all of the data. For example, if you've got a `Name` component, that renders the users name, they only care about `NAME_CHANGE_EVENT`. They don't want to re-render every single time a little thing happens. This is needless processing by React, although React will surmise nothing has changed and won't update the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Still debugging everywhere to get a better grasp on the inside of this pattern :) I made a mistake by saying `this.emit` triggers `addChangeListener`, that's not true. I did however, place a listener in the component that is supposed to get updated, but none of the functions actually trigger when an update happens. I will post the component in the OP.

Comment: And where have you defined `_addItem`?

Comment: Alright, this mistake was due to my own stupidity.. I forgot to add a _ to the  `this.onChange`, which should be `this._onChange`. Even after removing your added functions it still works like a charm (although I'm debugging the hell out of it to figure out why*).

Thanks though- I am voting your answer as solution as your potential improvement is a helpfull one and it pushed me into the right direction.

The _addItem() happens in a private function in the AppStore (which is global scoped, during compilation it gets wrapped in its own scope).

Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting that this question got a lot of traction. Must be a common problem.

Comment: The tutorial that I'm using is somewhat old and I've had to fix some other stuff myself, at first I thought it was just that others were running into the same kind of problems. Or, it's that React is a hot item.. Regardless, thanks again for the advice :)